# Стилизация AutoCompleteTextView в android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Добрый день! Есть небольшой вопрос:

имеется AutoCompleteTextView  такого вида:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2">
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/address_field"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:ems="11"
                android:hint="@string/address"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:textColor="#757575"
             />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Как его стилизовать, чтобы он выглядел с ограничителями по краям? Вот так:[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это обычный `9-patch` фон. [Тут](http://android-holo-colors.com/) вы можете создать себе тему с выбранным цветом

Comment: Спасибо огромное)